# Find the sharpest lower bound $c$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Fix an even number $n$. The random variables $X_1 , X_2 ,...,X_n$ take values in the set {−1, 1}. There is a constant $c$ so that, for $i \neq j$, $E[X_i X_j ] = c$. Find the sharpest
>   lower bound you can for $c$.

I think $c$ should be greater than or equal to zero, but cannot prove it. Can you give me some ideas?

PS: Please don't downvote my problem if you don't have any ideas. This problem does make sense, since it's a problem in an ivy school's prelim exam. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share what you've tried, and exactly what you're having trouble with? It is quite frequent that questions posed as isolated exercises are downvoted when they are dumped without any apparent thoughts or efforts from the asker.

Comment: I don't put my thoughts because I have no ideas on this problem, so I want to get some hints from other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random variable $(X_1+\dots+X_n)^2$ is non-negative, hence
$$ 0\leq \mathbb{E}[(X_1+\dots+X_n)^2]=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[X_i^2]+\sum_{i\neq j}\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j]=n+n(n-1)c$$
This implies that $c\geq -\frac{1}{n-1}$.

Thus it is enough to show that this bound is optimal. To do so, let $\Omega$ be the subset of $\{-1,1\}^n$ consisting of those sequences with an equal number of $1$s and $-1$s. Note that if $n=2k$ then $|\Omega|={n\choose k}$ since an element of $\Omega$ is determined by the positions of the $1$s.

Give $\Omega$ the uniform probability law, and let $X_i(\omega)$ be the $i$th entry of $\omega$. To compute $\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j]$, observe that there are ${n-2\choose k-2}$ elements of $\Omega$ such that $X_i(\omega)=1=X_j(\omega)$, ${n-2\choose k}$ elements of $\Omega$ such that $X_i(\omega)=-1=X_j(\omega)$, and $2{n-2\choose k-1}$ elements of $\Omega$ such that $X_i(\omega)$ and $X_j(\omega)$ have opposite signs. Therefore
$$ \mathbb{E}[X_iX_j]=\frac{{n-2\choose k}+{n-2\choose k-2}-2{n-2\choose k-1}}{{n\choose k}}$$
and this simplifies to $\frac{-1}{n-1}$ after some algebra if we recall that $n=2k$.

Comment: Why you only consider subset $\Omega$? I think if we want to compute $\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j]$, we should consider all the values from $\{-1,1\}^n$

Comment: I don't only consider a subset of $\Omega$. I defined $\Omega$ to be a subset of $\{-1,1\}^n$ having the properties I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have $a$ of the variables being $1$ and $n-a$ being $-1$.  Then for $i \neq j$, $E[X_iX_j]=\frac {a(a-1)+(n-a)(n-a-1)-a(n-a)}{n(n-1)}$  This will be minimized (you need to justify this) when $a=\frac n2$ which will give you your bound.

Comment: I think you should consider all the situations with different $a$ and also you don't know what is the probability of each $a$